# Melhor forma de fornecer Sessions para DAO's

Tags: hibernate, session, spring

Eu estava pesquisando na internet formas de injetar Sessions nas DAO's esta:

> HibernateUtil

Esta forma trata-se de implementar uma classe utilitária que irá configurar, instanciar e disponibilizar um objeto `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` que poderá ser utilizada globalmente (por toda a aplicação).

**Código base:**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY = buildSessionFactory();

    public HibernateUtil() {
        super();
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

        } catch (Throwable erro) {
            System.out
                    .println("Criação inicial do objeto Sessionfactory falhou. Erro: "
                            + erro);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(erro);
        }
    }
```

> Perguntas

1 - Uso Spring, então o Spring já me disponibiliza a instância do SessionFactory de acordo com a configuração que coloquei no arquivo de configuração do Spring. E criar uma classe, com uma propriedade do tipo SessionFactory que será injetada e um método para disponibilizá-lo parece desnecessário. Qual a melhor forma de disponibilizar Sessions para as DAO's utilizando o Spring? Talvez, utilizar AspectJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem sombras de dúvidas, **utilize o Spring**. Não utilize essas "classes utilitárias" que se vê muito por aí em projetos que vão para produção. Você até pode usar essas classes em testes, e algumas aplicações temporárias rápidas. Mas é uma péssima prática utiliza-las em projetos maiores.

O Spring oferece uma gama muito grande de classes e APIs para integrar sua aplicação com diversos frameworks e bibliotecas. Inclusive o próprio Hibernate ou JPA. Seria reinventar a roda em um projeto Spring utilizar classe utilitária.

Não vou entrar em detalhes de como fazer essa integração porque não acho que seja o escopo de sua pergunta. Mas vou deixar alguns links que podem te guiar nessa integração caso você tenha alguma dificuldade. Lógicamente, você pode voltar aqui no stackoverflow e tirar suas dúvidas com relação essa integração. Aí vão os links:

- [Hibernate 4 with Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring);
- [Spring 3.2.5.RELEASE and Hibernate 4 Integration Example Tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/08/spring-3-2-5-release-and-hibernate-4-integration-example-tutorial/)
- [Spring 4 integration with Hibernate 4](http://keyurj.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/spring-4-integration-with-hibernate-4.html)